# Is there a way to delay shutter release when using a remote shutter, possibly with the aid of Magic Lantern?

Tags: remote, magic-lantern

The remote I use for my Canon 550D unfortunately doesn't have a switch permitting me to either release the shutter instantaneously or after a delay pf 2 seconds. First of all it doesn't make sense to me that this setting would be on the remote rather than on the camera, where one could set an arbitrary delay.

**Question:** Is there a way too achieve arbitrary delay, possibly using tools like  Magic Lantern?

There are similar questions that indicate otherwise, but none of them address the possibility of using custom firmware.

Bonus Question: Why is it that the delay is set by a different infra-red signal rather than a setting on the camera?

Comment: The 550D has in-camera options for 2 seconds and 10 seconds delays, when you use a wired remote the camera will used those settings. I don't know about the IR remote or Magic Lantern

Answer (score 1):

On the back of the camera press the left arrow, this will access to the drive mode.
In all exposure modes this will give you an option that says 10sec/Remote control. It does not require a remote control, but allows one. If you press the on camera shutter or a wired remote this will delay the shutter by 10 sec. 
Using the infra red remote on this setting allows instant or 2 sec deley
In P, TV, AV, M and A-DEP modes you will also have an option for 2 sec delay in this menu. This works for on camera shutter or wired remote.

Comment: I have the choice between either remote or a delay. If i chose the delay, the ir-remote won't work.

Comment: Regardless of the mode.

Comment: If the Self-timer/remote setting is selected it will act as a timer if on camera shutter is pressed. If you are using the remote the delay is set on the remote, this may not apply to an after market remote. There is a separate 2sec self-timer which does not allow use of remote. Pages 71 and 204 in the user manual my help.

Comment: Yes, I know that this setting is usually on the remote. For me that is unfortunately not the case. However I really don't see a single reason why such a setting would be on the remote rather than on the camera. I also know that I can use the self-timer and press the on-camera-shutter. But this is exactly what i want to avoid by using a remote.